# Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity update to Xfce

Tags: unity, xubuntu, 15.04, xfce

I was wondering if it is possible to change my environment from Unity to Xfce on my Ubuntu 15.04 without changing the whole system to Xubuntu. If I'm assuming correctly, Xubuntu is a separate system, and I would have to conduct a whole format/install procedure which I would prefer to avoid. I heard Xfce is much faster and less memory-consuming than Unity. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes xfce is a pretty lightweight DE.
If you want the whole Xubuntu package it might be best to back up your data and reinstall, otherwise install the xfce4 package via the software center or the command line with

> sudo apt-get install xfce4

and you should consider installing the `xfce4-goodies` package for a lot of helpful extras to really bring the best of xfce out. If you want the whole Xubuntu baggage, you can install the `xubuntu-desktop` package, but that would leave you with a lot of duplicate applications.The unity applications should work fine with xfce too.You are better off if you cherry pick which xfce applications you want to install along/instead of the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

After the installation, reboot your PC and you should log in into XFCE. All your files and installed packages will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

To change Unity for Xfce, without reformatting or reinstalling your system, try this:

`Switch on` your computer.

Press and hold the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options.`

Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

Your computer should display a menu with a number of options.

Select a menu option and press `Enter` to use it in the following order:

`network`: Enable networking, which is disabled by default in recovery mode.

`root`: Leaves the menu and goes to a root shell prompt.

In the terminal run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(ubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'

apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tasksel to install desktops just like in Debian:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

Just don't install any of the "live" or "USB" desktops.

You can even choose a minimal install. Use your arrow keys and the <kbd>TAB</kbd> button to navigate. Use the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to toggle select.

Ubuntustudio (another xfce based desktop) isn't explicitly listed, however, it's included in the publishing, graphics, video production, or audio packages.